# Kineticjs propotional scaling of a canvas by CSS width and height. Mouse events destruction happens

Tags: javascript, css, kineticjs

I have an svg with d3 transition & scale on. I want to duplicate everything on it to a canvas with mouse events turned on. Doing it for the performance optimisation everything is going fine except the fact that when width and height of kineticsjs canvas is not 100%, mouse events get broken.

I found out that changing canvases CSS attrs such as position, top, left do not breaks mouse events, but only width and height other than 100% does. Is there a way to say kineticjs to recalculate a coordinates of objects on it without redrawing?

**Just to clarify: I don't want to redraw the canvas when scaling, otherwise there will not be any performance boost at all, so setScale() solution won't work**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by patching kineticjs:

After 9581 line I added:

```
    setStageScale: function(value) {
        this.stageScale = value;
    },
```

And in method _setPointerPosition I changed last statement to this:

```
       if (x !== null && y !== null) {
            var canvasScale = this.stageScale || 1;
            this.pointerPos = {
                x: x / canvasScale,
                y: y / canvasScale
            };
        }
```

Now I just have to .setStageScale(scale) to notify kineticjs that my canvas is scaled